# Равнозначно ли вызов delete и деструктора для указателя

Tags: указатели, c++

Например у нас есть указатель какого-то типа:

```
Type* obj = new Type;
```

И два варианта:
1)

```
delete obj;
```

и
2)

```
obj->~Type();
```

Приведет ли (2) к тому же результату, что и (1), то есть к освобождению участка памяти, на который указывает obj?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Конечно, нет. При вызове delete сначала запускается деструктор, а потом освобождается динамически выделенная в куче под объект память. Если только в деструкторе нет чего-то типа

```
 delete this;
```

Но последнее - очень плохой стиль программирования.